# process every single row of data.table without key

Tags: r, data.table

I often need to process a data.table row by row, without grouping. For the moment I use `nrow` in `by` (thanks @AnandaMahto for the idea):

```
dt1[,{
# my code here
}, by = 1:nrow(dt1)]
```

is there more correct way to do that?

Comment: I don't think you need to actually create the temp ID, but can just use that in `by` (like `by = 1:nrow(dt1)`). Not sure if that's the most correct way either though.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, thanks, this already looks much nicer! I will edit my question to include this solution, maybe somebody will show even better way.

Comment: Why would you specify any `by` if you do not need it?

Comment: because without specifying `by`, the part of `{#my code here}` will be executed for the group of all rows while I need it to be executed for every row separately

Comment: Doing by row operations are very inefficient in R and usually should be avoided at all cost. There is also no big advantage in using `data.table` when running by row operations. I think you should explain what you actually trying to achieve and maybe we would be able to help to achieve the same result *without* doing it by row.

Comment: Also see [FR #1063](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1063)